# Jquery slider previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

The issue with this code is on the previous button. When the user press previous on the first slide there is a blank slider for a few seconds and then the last slide appears. Would you know how to make this slide action smooth, thanks for reading...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/scripts/SliderControl.js"></script>
    <link href="/Styles/Sliders.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="text-muted">jQuery Basic Slider</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="Images/Image1.jpg" alt="About Us" width="720" height="400" />
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="Images/Image2.jpg" alt="About Us" width="720" height="400" />
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="Images/Image3.jpg" alt="About Us" width="720" height="400" />
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="Images/Image4.jpg" alt="About Us" width="720" height="400" />
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="Images/Image6.jpg" alt="About Us" width="720" height="400" />
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="Images/Image1.jpg" alt="About Us" width="720" height="400" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <img id="Next" src="Images/RightArrow.png"
             class="img-responsive NextButton" />
        <img id="Previous" src="Images/LeftArrow.png"
             class="img-responsive PreButton" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>


#slider {
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider .slide {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
}


#Next
{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}

    #Next:hover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }

#Previous
{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}

    #Previous:hover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }

#slider .NextButton
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2%;
}

#slider .PreButton
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 2%;
}




'use strict';

$(function () {

    //settings for slider
    var width = 720;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    //cache DOM elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
    var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $slideContainer.animate({ 'margin-left': '-=' + width }, animationSpeed, function () {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    }
    function pauseSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    $slideContainer
        .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
        .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

    startSlider();

    $('#Next').click(function () {

            $slideContainer.animate({ 'margin-left': '-=' + width }, animationSpeed, function () {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
    });

    $('#Previous').click(function () {

        //if (currentSlide === 1) {
        //    $slideContainer.animate({ 'margin-left':  -1 * width * ($slides.length -2)}, animationSpeed, function () {
        //        currentSlide = $slides.length - 1;
        //    });
        //}
        //else { 
            $slideContainer.animate({ 'margin-left': '+=' + width }, animationSpeed, function () {
                if (--currentSlide === 0) {
                    currentSlide = $slides.length - 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', -1 * width * ($slides.length - 2));

                }
                }); 
            //}
        });


    $('#Next')
        .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
        .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

    $('#Previous')
        .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
        .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

});
```

Comment: Is your CSS code not inside `<style>` tag? Jquery code also not inside `<script>` tag?

Comment: I pasted all code in one go. In the real situation the css and javascript are in two different filesSliders.css and Slidercontrol.js respectively. Code visibility in not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

your code is a little bit confuse for a slider.
I simplified for you in an easy way to understand. We can use just one method to move the slider and in the previous and next buttons increase or decrease the currentSlide variable.

Update you js code with this code bellow. Any questions, just ask. =)

```
'use strict';

$(function () {

    /**
     * Variables
     */
    var width = 720,
        animationSpeed = 600,
        pause = 3000, 
        currentSlide = 0,
        $slider = $('#slider'),
        $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider),
        $slides = $('.slide', $slider),
        interval;

    /**
     * Methods
     */
    function changeSlider () {
        // verify the boundaries of slider
        if(currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = $slides.length - 1;
        if(currentSlide == $slides.length) currentSlide = 0;

        console.log(currentSlide);

        // animation using the currentSlide variable 
        $slideContainer.animate({ 
            'margin-left': -(currentSlide * width) 
        }, animationSpeed);
    }

    function startInterval() {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            // increase the currentSlide in each interval dispatch
            currentSlide++;
            changeSlider();
        }, pause);
    }

    function pauseInterval() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    /**
     * Mouse Events
     */
    $slideContainer
        .on('mouseenter', pauseInterval)
        .on('mouseleave', startInterval);

    $('#Next').click(function () {
        // next button, decrease
        currentSlide--;
        changeSlider();
    });

    $('#Previous').click(function () {
        // previous button, increase
        currentSlide++;
        changeSlider();
    });

    $('#Next')
        .on('mouseenter', pauseInterval)
        .on('mouseleave', startInterval);

    $('#Previous')
        .on('mouseenter', pauseInterval)
        .on('mouseleave', startInterval);

    /** 
     * Initialize Slider
     */
    changeSlider();
    startInterval();
});
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't answer the question. The previous function should function the same as the next function.

Comment: Sorry, you're trying to animate first and verify the position and variables later, because of it, you are getting the blank step when you press the previous button.

Comment: Your missing the point. Your code will show all images as it navigates to from the first image to the last image on pressing the previous button on the first slide. It should slide from the first image to the last image.